# How to sort product collection based on manufacturer options?

Tags: product-collection, sorting

I'm trying following code for  sorting by manufacturer options(for example sony, nokia, samsung).

But unfortunately its not working.Can you help me any one .

```
$prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('manufacturer', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Couple of questions. Did you add manufacturer to the flat categories index and what kind of sorting behaviour are you expecting?